# Do not discover everything with discovery rule

Tags: zabbix

I'm trying to monitor Routerboard Mikrotik devices using Zabbix.
So far so good... My only issue is that i'm using a discovery rule, this rule discover and create a graph for every single interface inside my MK
ether1 ether2 ether3 ether4 pppoe1 pppoe2 pppoe3 pppoe4 pppoe5 etc
I want this just to discover some specific vlans.
How can i do that?
I'm totally new to Zabbix and have no clue of *** i'm doing.

edit1:sorry about my bad english and my language.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the filtering for [low level discovery](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.4/manual/discovery/low_level_discovery) rules. For including, you can use a regexp directly in the LLD rule. For negating, using [global regexps](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.4/manual/regular_expressions#global_regular_expressions) will be easier.

See the default Linux and SNMP templates for examples on filtering and using global regexps.